# Liquibase error when Comment at the end of sql file

Tags: sql, liquibase

When add any comments to the end of sql file liquibase raises an error.
Everything is ok in any other places.
What are we doing wrong?

`version 4.1.1 #10 built at 2020-10-12 19:24+0000 Starting Liquibase at 09:43:04 (version 4.1.1 #10 built at 2020-10-12 19:24+0000) Unexpected error running Liquibase: Migration failed for change set 1000.file_name.sql::1::10000: Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED [Failed SQL: (17439) – problem comment] For more information, please use the --logLevel flag`

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset 1:10000 stripComments:false runOnChange:true endDelimiter:;
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.SOME_TABLE modify
"ANY_COLOMN varchar2(60 char)
;
commit
;
-- problem comment
```

UPD
The command I'm running:

```
liquibase.bat --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --username=yyyy --password=xxxx --url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=some_host.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=some_servicename))) --changeLogFile=db-changelog-test.yml update
```

db-changelog-test.yml

```
---
databaseChangeLog:
- include:
  file: 1000.file_name.sql
  relativeToChangelogFile: true
```

liquibase.bat: modified only one string

```
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_OPTS set JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: This case did not repeat. Can you add more information.

If you are using **Apache Maven** add `pom.xml` and `liquibase.properties`.
If you are using **Liquibase CLI** then add command and `liquibase.properties`.

Comment: Updated. I don't use the liquibase.properties